# Is It Possible to Click on a Link and Proceed with Testing Upon Page Timeout Error?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a hard time with setting up page timeout rules and clicking on a link.

If the page takes too long to load after clicking a link, then I get `Timed out receiving message from renderer: xx.xxx`

Once this happens, the whole test case stops working. It doesn't execute any code after this.

```
int timeout = 10;
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I also did wrap my `driver.get()` in a `try-catch` block. Since the issue is clicking on a link rather than opening a new page, it doesn't seem to be working.

Could anyone shed some light into this?

Comment: You will have to debug it an see where the issues is, if this happens manually. Increase timeout, create a method that waits for the page to be loaded.Identify the issue first, maybe you have an environment issue, see if this happens on a certain page on when doing certain actions. 10 seconds may be too little if your environment is doing some payment processing for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply lauda. Unfortunayely increasing timeout is not an option. Sometimes some pages takes ages to load and the element I want to work on is already on the page. If I stop the page load manually it can proceed with the test if not sometimes I have to wait extra minute or two for page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you have an environment issue.

As i know, by default, all the automation frameworks waits for the page to be loaded between steps.

The automation should be relatively fast.
You should talk with the dev/ops team to increase the server resources, else you will waste to much time on debugging and execution of the automation suite.

A slow environment can cause a lot of issues and result in unreliable results.

You can create/use some conditional method like wait seconds for element and maybe use a optional parameter for time that you can change in special cases to 15-40 seconds if you have for example some payment method that requires extra time.

As a conclusion if the environment is slow then is not good for automation, you need to think what automation should do, what is the purpose of automating(that includes reliability + speed).

Comment: Unfortunately this might not be the case every single time. What I'm trying to do is create an app which I can set up most common tests I have to do via a GUI (swing app). Unfortunately sometimes the old developer is not available so I have to do few tests myself get the results and if client wants make a work around. I even found myself needing to do A/B testing with help of VPN and changing IP to specific country (usually landing pages and call to actions)